# Updating a mesh along a curve

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, bezier, procedural-generation

I am looking for a method to modify a procedural mesh along a curve. (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) by creating reference Vector3 points along this curve and subsequently updating the various mesh arrays accordingly.

I believe I need to create a vector3 array from the curve by setting each vector3 index to the curves transform at that transform.
This can be done with objects but i'm uncertain if this would work for vector3 arrays E.g:

```
For (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++, p++) { //gets the array length of custom mesh
    Transform item = Instantiate(items[i]) as Transform; // instantiates item as transform
    Vector3 position = spline.GetPoint(p * stepSize); //references my curve point and creates position vector each update
    item.transform.localPosition = position; //transforms instantiate item to curve point position
}
```

The second issue to tackle is then using this array of vectors to add to my mesh.
Each mesh component operates similarly so I'll use triangles as an example:

Initial triangles: (on start method)

```
0,2,1
2,3,1
```

On each update I wish to naturally add 2 more triangles 
The follow set of triangles would be for example :

```
2,4,3
4,5,3
```

(Unfortunately I cannot post images due to reputation limit)
this follows the rule that for each new triangle set:

```
Triangle I0+2 = (Triangle I1 + 2, Triangle I1 + 1, Triangle I1 +2)
Triangle I0+3 = (Triangle I2 + 2, Triangle I2 + 1, Triangle I1 +2)
```

Verticies would be added to a dynamic list by using the 'instantiated' vector3 coordinates from the curve.

I have seen a few attempts on a similar issues, however this method of updating  I have yet to see discussed as it appears others have chosen to use mesh dimension update methods. Obviously this is impractical considering the use of a curve.

Comment: Appreciate the edit chaps.

Comment: Update:
 Managed to get Lists finally working (appear to have a seemingly random bug when using System.Collections.Generic)

Comment: Update 2:
My mistake to assume a new triangle could reference the previous.
The following triangles would be : 4,5,6  4,6,7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much tinkering I found the answer:

Take a float distance across three bezier curves in parallel.
On update store the these three points as vectors.
Adjust distance var and get all your vectors along each curve into a list via a for loop.
on each for loop instance create triangles into your vector2 list.
Once points are all calculated : create your mesh and boom one customisable track/road/path -Just be sure to include mesh renderer,rigid body,collider and filter.